# Maximum number of words we can write in android studio string (xml text)

Tags: android-studio, android-fragments, textview, android-xml, android

What is the maximum number of words we can write in android studio xml "text".
I was making a glossary of words that I can use for my own purpose. I cut and paste a 5000 lines of glossary in

TextView 
android:text="glossary".

When I build and installed apk there were no texts. It was blank, however, if I use only one line, then it shows that line.
Please guide me.
How I can write a long list in fragment_glossary.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There is no Lenght limit by default.
2. Use string.xml for inflating any Strings in TextView.
3. If your data is dynamic use JAVA Object:-

   String mString = "your very long text string";

   Textview mTextview = (Textview) findViewById(R.id.textViewId);

   mTextview.setText(mString);